# Large Vue component for single use in HTML

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have an editor vue component `<editor></editor>` that I want to use on only a few sites. This component is fairly big (400kb), so I don't want to register it globally. Is there a way to do this? The site is a traditional server side app that uses normal blade.

I'm thinking about manually importing it only on the sites that use it.

Comment: Yes, manual import in those specific views/components would be the way to go.

Comment: Do you have a resource on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `editor` component like this:

```
...
import EditorComponent from 'path/to/editor/'

export default {
  components: {
    'editor': EditorComponent
  }
}
...
```

Then you can use the `<editor></editor>` without troubles in your HTML.

Comment: But the site itself isn't a vue component, its normal blade

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention blade. I assumed it was a pure-vue project.

Comment: Sorry, I've ment to say that with "The site is a traditional server side app."

Comment: Add that in your question so another person can help you. I wouldn't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Chunk your javascript with Webpack, this way you only load what you need in the front end.
[Example of code splitting](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/08/vue-js-3-ways-code-splitting-webpack/)

Then use different new Vue functions to render only what is needed

```
import Editor from './Editor.vue'
import OtherVueInstance from './OtherVueInstance.vue'
window.onload = function () {
    if (pageContainsEditor) {
        new Vue({
            render: h => h(Editor)
        }).$mount('#editor');   
    } else if (somethingElse) {
        new Vue({
            render: h => h(OtherVueInstance)
        }).$mount('#OtherVueInstance');   
    }
}
```

In the blade file:

```
<div id="editor"></div>
<div id="OtherVueInstance"></div>
```

Also you can just create a whole new Vue application, with its own seperate JS and CSS. Then just load that on the pages where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your Editor component as [async component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Instead of this:

```js
import Editor from './editor'
export default {
  components: {
    Editor
  }
}
```

Do this:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    Editor: () => import('./editor')  
  }
}
```

Webpack will split Editor component code into separate chunk and Vue will load it on demand only when it is actually needed...